# What is the difference between the two wording when the two-dimensional array is a function parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

What is the difference between the two wording when the two-dimensional array is a function parameter?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void dfs(int (*a)[10]){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
void dfs2(int a[][10]){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            cout<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    }
}
int main(){

    int (*a)[10]=new int[5][10];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            a[i][j]=i*j;
        }
    }
    dfs(a);
    dfs2(a);
    delete []a;
    return 0;
}
```

`dfs(int (*a)[10])` and `dfs2(int a[][10])` all can work,I want to know when the array very large,Will that be efficient?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between the two wording when the
>   two-dimensional array is a function parameter?

There is none.

That's also why you get a redefinition error if you try to give both functions the same name.

Nevertheless, the `dfs(int (*a)[10])` version is of greater eductional value, because it shows you that arrays cannot be passed by value; when you attempt to do so, a pointer is passed instead and the size information is lost. You end up with a pointer to an `int[10]` object, which may or may not be the beginning of a whole array of `int[10]`s.

> I want to know when the array very large,Will that be efficient?

As there is no difference at all, it also doesn't matter how large your arrays are. Efficiency is a completely unrelated topic, too.

---

In any case, drop all the array stuff and use `std::vector`. And don't use the non-standard `<bits/stdc++.h>` header, and don't use `<windows.h>` if you don't need the Windows API. And finally, avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: There are advantages to having a multidimensional matrix contiguous.  But a `std::array` of `std::array` will do that just as well as raw arrays without all the headaches.

Comment: @guanjun: I didn't say anything about causing memory leaks. However, you are right when you say that raw dynamically allocated arrays can easily cause memory leaks. This is one of the reasons you want to avoid them.